# How to verify a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, verification

A famous actor in my country asked me to help him verify his Facebook page, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Requesting a blue verification badge](https://www.facebook.com/help/1288173394636262/)

- Verify you have all that in the list, and submit a request with an official government issued photo identification. It's encouraged to include additional information to help review your request.

Note: It seems that the option for requesting verification isn't available in every country.

> #### How do I request a blue verification badge?
>
> ...
>
> To request a blue verification badge, your Page or profile must comply with Facebook's [terms of service](https://www.facebook.com/terms) and have the following:
>
> - A [cover photo](https://www.facebook.com/help/220070894714080?helpref=faq_content)
> - A [profile photo](https://www.facebook.com/help/163248423739693?helpref=faq_content)
> - A [name](https://www.facebook.com/help/519912414718764?helpref=faq_content) that follows Facebook's guidelines
> - Content posted to the account
> - [“Follow”](https://www.facebook.com/help/203141666415461?helpref=faq_content) enabled (profiles only)
>
> You can submit a request by filling out [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/342509036134712). We require a copy of your official government-issued photo identification (example: passport, driver's license, national identification card) to validate your request. We encourage you to include additional information to help us better review your request. Please include a few sentences explaining why the account should receive the blue verification badge and relevant URLs that help illustrate public interest for the account.

Comment: There's no form to fill anymore for facebook

Comment: Sorry, answer updated.

Comment: the verification form on facebook doesn't exist anymore, how to submit the details you mentioned to facebook?

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't exist? [Here it is](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/342509036134712) - you should first verify that the things on the list are configured correctly, and than fill [this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/342509036134712) to request the verification

Comment: could you please screenshot what you see? I see https://imgur.com/a/rgHA0b9

Comment: Very weird. On this link: **https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/342509036134712**   I see that: https://imgur.com/G4CdlsM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76319/discussion-between-arieljannai-and-lynob).

Comment: @Sathya - Why did you changed the title to say that it's not available right now? I haven't seen any note about it

Comment: I'm guessing it was a mistake from before the question was split (twitter process is not available at the moment). I rolled back your edit. If you were right about it not being available, please add some information about it, or a source. Thanks!

Comment: Both Facebook and twitter arent available at least in my country, there's nothing that can be done about it so i just accepted your answer and moved on

Comment: @Lynob, my last message was meant for Sathya, since he edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, where are you from? Are they completely unavailable, or just part of them?

Comment: @arieljannai because it is not available right now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Byx.png

Comment: @Sathya for me it is: https://i.imgur.com/0ZSWKzM.png

Comment: Very weird. Maybe it's country related - where are you from?

Comment: @arieljannai mostly probably country limited. best to have both entries. I'm from India

Comment: @Sathya I added a note about it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/1288173394636262/?ref=u2u):

> Requesting a blue verification badge isn't available right now.

There are [two types of verification badge](https://www.facebook.com/help/196050490547892):

- Gray Verification Badge
- Blue Verification Badge

See:
[How do I request a gray verification badge for my Page](https://www.facebook.com/help/100168986860974/?ref=u2u)
[How do I request a blue verification badge](https://www.facebook.com/help/1288173394636262/?ref=u2u)

**Currently both are not available.** But if your account doesn't have a blue verification badge, there are other ways to help let people know that you're authentic. For example, you can link to your Facebook profile or Page from your official website, Instagram profile or Twitter account.

Comment: Check out the discussion on my answer, the verification seems not to be available on every country. I can submit a request for the blue badge (which is the only one exists right now). I also stated that it's not available on every country