# How to verify a Twitter account?

Tags: twitter, verification

Someone asked me to help him verify his Twitter account, how to do that? So that there's a blue tick next to his name.

Comment: Note, this was split from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116472/how-to-verify-a-facebook-page at my request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Currently suspended due to work on a new authentication verification program](https://twitter.com/verified/status/968243242184491008).

- Follow [@verified](https://twitter.com/verified) for updates.

> We've paused public submissions for verification.  <sup><sub>(posted on 11:55 PM - 26 Feb 2018)</sub></sup>
>
> > We're working on a new authentication and verification program. In the meantime, we are not accepting any public submissions for verification and have introduced new guidelines for the program.
> >
> > [Verified account FAQs](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/twitter-verified-accounts)

In general:

> #### What types of accounts get verified?
>
> An account may be verified if it is determined to be an account of public interest. Typically this includes accounts maintained by users in music, acting, fashion, government, politics, religion, journalism, media, sports, business, and other key interest areas.

In addition, [this](https://www.wikihow.com/Get-a-Verified-Account-on-Twitter) is a wikihow guideline on getting a verified account on twitter, which I believe will still be relevant - it gives guidelines on how to improve your profile (quality, activity, publicity etc.)